# $f$ integrable iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a measure space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal P(\Bbb R), \mu_\Bbb N)$  where $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ denotes the power set of $\Bbb R$ and $\mu_\Bbb N$ is defined by $\mu_\Bbb N(A)= \vert {A \cap \Bbb N}\vert$= quantity of natural numbers in $A$,

how can I show that the function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is $\mu_\Bbb N$-integrable if and only if the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ absolutely converges , where $\int f d\mu_\Bbb N$ =$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Bbb R, \mathcal P(\Bbb R), \mu_\Bbb N)$ where $\mu_\Bbb N(A)= \vert {A \cap \Bbb N}\vert$= quantity of natural numbers in $A$,  $\int f d\mu_\Bbb N$ =$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$.

Define the space $L^1(\Bbb R, \mathcal P(\Bbb R),\mu_\Bbb N)=\{f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \int_{\Bbb R} \vert f \vert d\mu_\Bbb N <\infty \}$ that is the space of the integrable functions

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ absolutely converges, means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert f(n) \vert <\infty$ which means exactly $\int_{\Bbb R} \vert f \vert d\mu_\Bbb N <\infty$.

Now you need to prove $f$ integrable entails $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ absolutely converges, which is trivial as well by passing through the definition

$f$ integrable = $f \in L^1(\Bbb R, \mathcal P(\Bbb R),\mu_\Bbb N) \rightarrow \infty >\int_{\Bbb R} \vert f \vert d\mu_\Bbb N = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert f(n) \vert$

Comment: Thanks. Why does $\int_{\Bbb R} \vert f \vert d\mu_\Bbb N <\infty$ imply that $f$ is integrable? Is it because it implies that negative part and positive part of $f$ are finite?

Comment: Yes that is exacty why, try splitting $f=f^+ - f^-$ to see it!

Comment: Okay much appreciated. Just another question to have a better understanding: There was someone commenting that it is not even true, what is wrong about his example $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin \pi x}{x}$?

Comment: The fact is that he was using the theorem "f Riemann-integrable implies f Leb-Integrable and the two integrals coincide", however this theorem holds for the classic Leb-Integral, defined on $(\Bbb R, \mathcal L(\Bbb R), \lambda)$ which is not your case!